# Filtering pyspark sql for max date

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have sql that is joining several different tables together.  I need this data to also be filtered by the max (or most recent) value in the vers_dt column (this column is dates as a strings) from the wcd_vers table.  I've been trying to add where clauses but nothing is working.  I end up getting an error that begins like this:

```
no viable alternative at input
```

Here's a snippit of the SQL I'm working with.  I only need the data filtered based on the above.  I don't actually need the vers_dt column to appear in my final table

```
  FROM its.WKLD_PDN AS B 
  INNER JOIN its.PT_STRUC AS C 
  ON B.wkld_pdn_id = C.wkld_pdn_id 
  AND B.location_cd = C.location_cd 
  **INNER JOIN its.WCD_VERS AS D** 
  ON C.dsasemb_wcd_id = SUBSTR(D.wcd_vers_id, 1,6) 
  AND C.location_cd = D.location_cd 
  INNER JOIN its.WCD_SUB_OP AS E 
  ON D.wcd_vers_id = E.wcd_vers_id 
  AND D.location_cd = E.location_cd
 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN its.SUB_OP_DET AS F 
  ON REPLACE(E.wcd_sub_op_id,'.00','') = REPLACE(F.wcd_sub_op_id,'.00','')
  AND E.location_cd = F.location_cd 
--  WHERE D.vers_dt IS NULL             -- 2023.08.15 removed this
--  AND E.trig_wcd_id IS NOT NULL       -- which caused a rewording of this 
  WHERE E.trig_wcd_id IS NOT NULL   -- to this
  AND SUBSTR(C.dsasemb_wcd_id, 6, 1) = 'W'
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the WCD_VERS table before joining.

The following code snippet limits the WCD_VERS data to only the rows where vers_dt is the latest date. Then the INNER JOIN only joins to this limited dataset.

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
    SUBSTR(wcd_vers_id, 1,6) wcd_vers_id_substr
    FROM its.WCD_VERS 
    WHERE vers_dt = (SELECT max(vers_dt) 
                        FROM its.WCD_VERS)
) AS D 
  ON C.dsasemb_wcd_id = D.wcd_vers_id_substr
```

More examples: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php

Note this will do a full table scan of the WCD_VERS table in order to identify the max(vers_dt). There are alternative approaches you could consider if the vers_dt column is a partition.